# Pass array between View Controllers

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

Trying to pass an array between view controllers. I am not sure why as pretty sure that the array has something in it, still when it arrives on the other side it seems to be empty. No errors... just empty.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == "segueMapSelection" {

           if let destinaton = segue.destination as? MapTableChoiceViewController {
                //destinaton.maps = sender as? [SkiMap]
                print("size of array before passing it through: ", maps.count)
                destinaton.maps = self.maps
           }
      }
     }

     @IBAction func SelectDifferentMapButton(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
          performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueMapSelection", sender: self.maps)


     }
```

On my receiving ViewController I have a

```
var maps : [ObjectTypeHere]! = []
```

Any idea what I am doing here? I have left the code commented of the other way I tried. When I tried that it gave an error.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: var maps : [ObjectTypeHere]! Only this in your second view controller

Comment: Ok... so I did that and it probably is showing me the problem. It now says: Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Ok so, the arrays has the same type? Your second view controller array is ObjectTypeHere maybe you did that for the example but im asking anyway

Comment: Change this segue.destination as? MapTableChoiceViewController to this: segue.destination as! MapTableChoiceViewController i think there is the problem

Comment: Or just do: (segue.destination as! MapTableChoiceViewController).maps = self.maps only that line after checking the segue name

Comment: Yes, the ObjectTypeHere is the same. I have tried making the change to (segue.destination as! MapTableChoiceViewController).maps = self.maps  and now I am getting a Could not casdt value of type [destinationController]. Which just shows how much of an idiot I am... wrong view controller! All solved now! Tks for your help Lucas, part of your solution and part my stupidity!

Comment: please also not you are passing a copy of the array.  not the a reference.  so any changes in your new viewController's array will not be reflected in the original array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the sequence of things in view controller life cycles.

- self.maps is collect at some point in the source VC
- the segue begins, and reaches `prepare(for segue:)` occurs, which passes self.maps to the destination VC
- only then does the destination controller (MapTableChoiceViewController) execute viewDidLoad, which (re)initializes the array

For that reason, if you declare the array as:

```
var maps:[ObjectTypeHere]!
```

You should have passed the array successfully - of course, assuming the object type between `self.maps` and `designation.maps` are the same.

For a full definition of the sequence of events, [here's](http://vastdevblog.vast.com/blog/2012/04/08/uiviewcontroller-life-cycle/) a detailed description.